# Dialogflow V1 generating invalid actions.json?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm getting this error trying to release an older action that is still using Dialogflow V1 to Alpha:

[image]

​"Intent `actions.event_CANCEL` is using the reserved namespace. Please choose a name that does not start with 'actions'"

Note the period and underscore in the event name.

I don't have a Dialogflow Intent named this, so I assume this is from the actions.json file that Dialogflow is generating for the Action, but I can't see this.

I've deleted the two intents I had that had the actions_event_CANCEL event, but I'm still getting this. Unless it isn't regenerating it or something.

Anyone have any other thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: did you tried exporting to other agent and see if it is coming? sometimes such weird issues happen because of caching, try and see if clearing browser cache and cookies help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha releases are only supported on Dialogflow v2.